# How to timeout gets.chomp

Tags: ruby, gets

I am trying to write a program that will ask the user to answer a question using `gets.chomp` in three seconds or the answer will automatically return false.

I figured out everything except for the timeout part and I was wondering if anyone could please help.

Comment: Look at [Timeout](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `timeout` standard library

```
require "timeout"

puts "How are you?"
begin
  Timeout::timeout 5 do
    ans = gets.chomp
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  ans = nil
end
puts (ans || "User did not respond")
```

Read more about the library http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Kernel::select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Kernel.html#method-i-select) to write helper method like this:

```rb
def gets_with_timeout(sec, timeout_val = nil)
  return gets.chomp if select([$stdin], nil, nil, sec)
  timeout_val
end
```

Then you can use it like this:

```rb
puts "How are you?"
ans = gets_with_timeout(5)
puts ans || "User did not respond"
```

Answer (score -7):

I wrote some code for this.

```
def question_time
  puts "Your question here"
  t = Time.now
  answer = gets.chomp
  Time.now - t > 3 ? false : answer
end
```

Comment: The problem is that `gets` will block indefinitely, so if the user does nothing, the program will never end.

Comment: This answer is wrong. I recommend removing it.
It completely disregards the core of the question and, apart from that, I don't know how and when this code should ever be useful.
The question asks for a program that automatically returns false if the user has not answered within 3 seconds, but this code will wait (forever) until the user gives input, as, `gets` blocks execution.